# 2`s complement error in python

Tags: python, bitarray

I am trying to read a  3 byte 2`s complement value from serial port and i am trying to plot the value , for this i am using the following

```
out=  BitArray(int = value_1, length = 24).int
```

when i pass the value in 0x7FFFFF instead value_1 i am getting the correct result that is 8388607

if i am trying the get the value form serial port (value_1) and passing this to the above line i am getting the following error

CreationError: 7fffff is too large a signed integer for a bitstring of length 24. The allowed range is [-8388608, 8388607].

if i print the value_1 before send it for processing it prints 7fffff

pls let me know what is wrong in the above value passing

Comment: What do you get if you `print type(value_1)`? - It might help to mention in your question that BitArray is from the bitstring library as many might not have it installed and __how__ you are reading from the serial port.

Comment: when i used print type(value_1) output was <type 'str'>

Comment: i am using the following lines to read the data from the serial portinput_data = ser.read(3)             
             Received_Data.append(input_data.encode("hex"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your value from the serial library is a string you need to inform BitArray the representation and get rid of the int=

```
from bitstring import BitArray
i = '7FFFFF'
BitArray('0x%s' % i, length=24).int # Returns 8388607
i = '8FFFFF'
BitArray('0x%s' % i, length=24).int # Returns -7340033
i = 'FFFFFF'
BitArray('0x%s' % i, length=24).int # Returns -1
```

Comment: @VijayR - if it worked it might be nice to either up vote _if you think there might be another __better__ answer_ and/or mark as answered - that way if other people are having similar problems they can see what worked.

Comment: @ Steve , I dont think i have the privilege to vote i am pretty new to this site

Comment: @VijayR Since it is your question you __must__ have the ability mark it as your answer.

Comment: Or just `BitArray(hex=i).int` works fine in these cases.